# Datatables DOM ajax datasource

Tags: jquery, datatables

Normaly a ajax Datasource (for Datatables) looks like this:

```
"aaData": [
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", 4, "X" ],
            [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 5.0", "Win 95+", 5, "C" ]
]
```

Is it possible to have a **DOM** response to an ajax request in Datatables ?
and have the server respond with **html** instead of **Json** ?

I would like to be able to just return the **html**:

```
<tr>
 <td>cell 11</td>  <td>cell 12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>cell 21</td>  <td>cell 22</td>
</tr>
```

This html example is a simplification, I want to return html because some of my columns are more complicated than just a simple text or date field.

**NOTE:**
I imagine this could be done with **fnRowCallback**, by generating the html code on the client side and using the normal **Json** response data, but it seems a bit unelegant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually generate the code server side withouth problems and send the html back as json

```
"aaData": [
    [ "<a href.....>Trident</a>", "<div class='myclass'>Internet Explorer 4.0</div>"],

]
```

in this way you generate  the html serverside and then it gets inserted as is in the `<td>`

Comment: tried this once but failed for me. I have to try again, maybe I had some error I didn't notice.
If/when it works I will mark it as the answer :D

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I didn't notice my html was generate with " instead of ' and messed up the entire response. Thank you very much.